# while calling the required function it performs the function which called eariler and then perform the relavant function

Tags: jquery, html

```
function upgradeconfirmbox(msg, mode, sender) {
    $(".blackout").css("display", "block");
    $(".container_cluster").addClass("blurcss");

    $(".pop-up-header-close").click(endBlackoutconfirmbox);
    $('.confirmlabel').text(msg);

    $(".confirmboxpopup").css("display", "block");
    $(".pop-up-footer-create-icon").click(
        { param1: mode, param2: sender }, 
        upgradeprocess
    );
    $(".pop-up-footer-create-icon").click(endBlackoutconfirmbox);
    $(".cancelprocess").click(endBlackoutconfirmbox);
}
```

when ever I call 2nd function after 1st function,1st function is called once again and then only 2nd function performs! I tried using different functions for these too.

```
function confirmbox(msg, mode, sender) {
    $(".blackout").css("display", "block");
    $(".container_cluster").addClass("blurcss");
    $(".pop-up-header-close").click(endBlackoutconfirmbox);
    $('.confirmlabel').text(msg);
    $(".confirmboxpopup").css("display", "block");
    $(".pop-up-footer-create-icon").click(
        { command:mode, cluster: sender},
        CallPopuCommands
    );
    $(".pop-up-footer-create-icon").click(endBlackoutconfirmbox);
    $(".cancelprocess").click(endBlackoutconfirmbox);
}
```

I used these function to call both of the functions,based on the button clicked the msg value in confirm box will be changed and the particular function will be called.
 function grid_dropdown(sender) {

```
    value = sender.childNodes[0].innerHTML;

    parentvalue = sender.parentElement.id;

    if (sender.childNodes[0].innerHTML == "Upgrade") {

        msg = "Are you sure you want to Upgrade?";

        upgradeflag = true;

        upgradeconfirmbox(msg, value, parentvalue, upgradeflag);
    }

    else if (sender.childNodes[0].innerHTML == "Finalize") {

            msg = "Are you sure you want to Finalize?";

       confirmbox(msg,value,parentvalue);

        }

        else if (sender.childNodes[0].innerHTML == "RollBack") {

            msg = "Are you sure you want to Rollback?";

          confirmbox(msg,value,parentvalue);
        }


        else
           {
            msg = "Are you sure you want to Continue?";

        confirmbox(msg, value, parentvalue);

          }

}
```

Html for upgrade

```
    <div class="pop-up-header">

        <div class="pop-up-header-label">UPGRADE</div>

        <div class="pop-up-header-close">X</div>

    </div>

    <div class="pop-up-form">

        <div>

            <div class="pop-up-row">
```

@Html.EJ().Uploadbox("UploadDefault").SaveUrl("SaveDefault").

RemoveUrl("RemoveDefault").ClientSideEvents(e => 

e.FileSelect("fileselect").Complete("completeupload").Begin("Beginupload"))

Choose file from your computer

```
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: why are you not adding these codes in the question itself???

Comment: better you have to add your code up to your tired Sangavi

Comment: I have added that,help me to resolve

Comment: can you show the html that goes with these click handlers?

Comment: Please, what is first and second function?? At this current state, the two functions you are displaying have absolutely no link together whatsoever. What is upgradeProcess? and CallPopuCommands? When is each called, and how?

Comment: I have used a customized confirm box to verify user's wish whether they want to do upgrade,delete etc. Based on the button clicked the partcular function will be called. I am using 1st function to perform upgrade and 2nd one to perform delete,finalize etc. whenever I finalize or delete(calling 2nd function) after upgrade(1st function) both of the functions are running.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are ADDING events on top of each other with these lines:

```
//In upgradeConfirmBox
$(".pop-up-footer-create-icon").click(
    { param1: mode, param2: sender }, 
    upgradeprocess
);
//In confirmbox
$(".pop-up-footer-create-icon").click(
    { command:mode, cluster: sender},
    CallPopuCommands
);
```

One those 2 lines have been executed at least once, both of the handlers they specify will be called. You should remove any click event before adding another like so:

```
//In upgradeConfirmBox
$(".pop-up-footer-create-icon").off("click").click(
    { param1: mode, param2: sender }, 
    upgradeprocess
);
//In confirmbox
$(".pop-up-footer-create-icon").off("click").click(
    { command:mode, cluster: sender},
    CallPopuCommands
);
```

See the manual about off at http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: Thanks for your response still I am facing the same error! And I need both the functions to be called whenever the respective button is clicked.